# C# UDPClient send data over global network

Tags: c#, udpclient

Server Code :

```
    Thread thdUDPServer;
    private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thdUDPServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread));
        thdUDPServer.Start();
    }

    UdpClient udpClient;
    public void serverThread()
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient(53);
        while (true)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            listBox1.Items.Add(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returnData.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Client Code :

```
    UdpClient udpClient;
    private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        udpClient.Connect(textBox1.Text, 53);
        Byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
        udpClient.Send(senddata, senddata.Length);
    }
```

Working on local network but i need global.

Details :

- Microsoft Defender off.
- Run as admin (For Server App and Client App)

Example :

```
udpClient.Connect(95.10.xxx.13, 53);
```

Where am I doing wrong?
How can i send data over global network using another method?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you send? Understand also that UDP does not guarantee delivery. So things could be working just fine, but for some reason one of the routers between you and the destination just isn't forwarding the packet.

Comment: @JimMischel I dont get an error. Nothing happens.

Comment: Does the router on the other end forward udp packets to host? Is the host on the other end in the DMZ?